# Unable to plot a network on igraph

Tags: r, plot, colors, igraph

My binary graph is based on an edgelist. Every vertex is a ticker on stock markets (eg : BARC= Barclay's)

```
    net_full_phase1=graph.edgelist(full_phase1, directed=FALSE)
V(net_full_phase1)$color=V(net_full_phase1)$name
V(net_full_phase1)$size=degree(net_full_phase1)
V(net_full_phase1)$color=gsub("BARC", "slategrey", V(net_full_phase1)$color)
V(net_full_phase1)$color=gsub("BNP", "blue", V(net_full_phase1)$color)
V(net_full_phase1)$color=gsub("CBK", "black", V(net_full_phase1)$color)
V(net_full_phase1)$color=gsub("WFC", "red", V(net_full_phase1)$color)
V(net_full_phase1)$color=gsub("BKIR", "orange", V(net_full_phase1)$color)
V(net_full_phase1)$color=gsub("ISP", "purple", V(net_full_phase1)$color)
V(net_full_phase1)$color=gsub("TPEIR", "lightblue", V(net_full_phase1)$color)
V(net_full_phase1)$color=gsub("SAB", "yellow", V(net_full_phase1)$color)
V(net_full_phase1)$color=gsub("BCP", "green", V(net_full_phase1)$color) 

plot(net_full_phase1, layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold)
```

I get this error :

> Error in symbols(x = coords[, 1], y = coords[, 2], bg = vertex.color,  : 
>     nom de couleur 'WFred' incorrecte

Just ran `unique(as.character(V(net_full_phase1)$name))`
here is the result :

```
"BARC"  "WFC"   "ISP"   "TPEIR" "BCP"   "SAB"   "BNP"   "CBK"   "BKIR"
```

I also ran : `table(V(net_full_phase1)$color)` with result :

```
black blue BredP green lightblue purple red redIR slategrey WFred yellow
```

Why isn't R considering some colors as "BredP", "redIR", "WFred"?

Comment: I think it's telling you that `gsub("WFC", "red", V(net_full_phase1)$color)` does not evaluate to a valid color... somehow, not obvious to me. I'd start by running that piece of code on its own, maybe wrapped in `table()`.

Comment: or extending Frank suggestion, after running all the gsub's have a look at `table(V(net_full_phase1)$color)`. What are the colours?

Comment: I'm able to run the code without the color specifications. As soon as I code the color, it's not working.

Just ran table(V(net_full_phase1)$color)

here is the result : 
    black      blue     BredP     green lightblue    purple       red     redIR slategrey     UredG     WFred    yellow

Comment: okay thanks. Well it clear that some of them are not colours.

Comment: it means that "orange" is "translated" as : UredG, WFred, redIR and BredP?

Comment: It means that your gsub is not having the expected result (see for example the result of `gsub("WFC", "red", "WFWFC")` ). The colour names , that you can see in the `table` call, need to be interpretable by igraph as colurs: `BredP`, `redIR`, `WFred` are not colours

Comment: I don't get it. Why does gsub consider "orange" as weird color such as BredP, redIR or WFred?
the result of gsub("WFC", "red", "WFWFC")) is WFred. but the code indicates to consider "red".

Comment: I dont understand why you think these (BredP, redIR or WFred) are being considered orange. I *think* these are the results of your gsub commnds not working as you expect. Can you edit your question with the result of `unique(as.character(V(net_full_phase1)$name))` please.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to edit my comment (I'm new on StackOverflow). What I mean is, when i run : table(V(net_full_phase1)$color), the result doesn't show "orange". That's why I thought gsub wouldn't consider "orange" as a color.

Just ran 
unique(as.character(V(net_full_phase1)$name))

Here is the result: 
 "BARC"  "WFC"   "ISP"   "TPEIR" "BCP"   "SAB"   "BNP"   "CBK"   "BKIR"

Comment: you should be able to edit your question. in the bottom left, under your question you should see an option <edit> (next to <delete>). Click that , add the details and then save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that something went amiss with your use of `gsub`. Below is the way I would approach this.

```
# Your vector of unique names 
nms <- c("BARC", "WFC", "ISP" ,"TPEIR" ,"BCP" ,"SAB" ,"BNP", "CBK" ,"BKIR")
```

Create small graph with same vertex names as in your example

```
library(igraph)
g <- random.graph.game(length(nms), 0.5)
V(g)$name <- nms
```

Create lookup table to match the names to colours: this assigns colours to the unique vertex names

```
lookup <- setNames(
  c("slategrey", "red", "purple", "lightblue", "green", "yellow", "blue", "black", "orange"),
  nms)

# have a look at object
lookup
#        BARC         WFC         ISP       TPEIR         BCP 
# "slategrey"       "red"    "purple" "lightblue"     "green" 
#         SAB         BNP         CBK        BKIR 
#    "yellow"      "blue"     "black"    "orange"
```

We can then use subset (`[`) to assign these to the vertex colour attribute

```
V(g)$color <- lookup[V(g)$name]
#  have a look at what is produced
V(g)$color 
# [1] "slategrey" "red"       "purple"    "lightblue" "green"    
# [6] "yellow"    "blue"      "black"     "orange"
```

Which produces

[image]

---

PS, I can't reproduce your `gsub` result: the code works okay

```
# Your vector of unique names 
nms <- c("BARC", "WFC", "ISP" ,"TPEIR" ,"BCP" ,"SAB" ,"BNP", "CBK" ,"BKIR")

nms = gsub("BARC", "slategrey", nms )
nms = gsub("BNP", "blue", nms )
nms = gsub("CBK", "black", nms )
nms = gsub("WFC", "red", nms )
nms = gsub("BKIR", "orange", nms )
nms = gsub("ISP", "purple", nms )
nms = gsub("TPEIR", "lightblue", nms )
nms = gsub("SAB", "yellow", nms )
nms = gsub("BCP", "green", nms )

# look at result
nms
# [1] "slategrey" "red"       "purple"    "lightblue" "green"     "yellow"    "blue"     
# [8] "black"     "orange"
```

Comment: Here is the code I modified, based on your answer.
#full_phase1 is the edgelist#

net_full_phase1=graph.edgelist(full_phase1, directed=FALSE)
V(net_full_phase1)$size=degree(net_full_phase1)
names<-c("BARC", "BNP", "CBK","WFC", "BKIR", "UCG","TPEIR", "SAB", "BCP")
lookup <- setNames(c("slategrey", "pink", "black", "red", "orange", "purple", "lightblue", "yellow", "green"), names)
V(net_full_phase1)$color<- lookup[names]
V(net_full_phase1)$color

plot(net_full_phase1, layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold)