# Is it possible/better to use sapply than a for loop for producing multiple igraph plots?

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, igraph

I've written a piece of script that uses the package igraph to produce a series of networks using a for loop. However, I have been told that using sapply/mapply etc. is better for doing this kind of thing in R. Can anyone tell me whether it would be possible to use sapply/mapply etc. to do this? If so could you point me in the right direction?

My code is below. glst is a list of igraph objects, so the code loops through the list producing the network maps for each igraph objects and saving them to a pdf.

```
for (name in mixedsort(names(glst))){
  i=delete.vertices(glst[[name]],which(degree(glst[[name]])<1))
  V(i)$color[V(i)$type  == 'nest']   <-  'orangered3'  
  V(i)$color[V(i)$type  == 'tree']   <-  "#228B2266"  
  V(i)$size <- 5
  V(i)$color[V(i)$species == 'larch'] <- 'burlywood4'
  V(i)$color[V(i)$species == 'SP'] <- 'darkgoldenrod2' 
  V(i)$color[V(i)$species == 'oak'] <- 'deepskyblue4' 
  V(i)$color[V(i)$species == 'silver birch'] <- 'deeppink' 
  V(i)$color[V(i)$species == 'sycamore'] <- 'forestgreen'
  V(i)$label.cex = 1
  plot(i, main =name, vertex.label.dist=0.5) 
  }
dev.off()
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is possible but here, it is IMO not better because sapply is also kind of a loop. You can very easily test this by changing the loop term into `sapply(mixedsort(names(glst)), function(name) { the_rest_of_your_code})`

Comment: A loop is better if you are just plotting the graph (as you seem to be doing) and not returning an object, (even though you are updating the each graph in glst by storing a vertex attribute). ( [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428534/unable-to-plot-a-network-on-igraph/40430953#40430953) offers an alternate approach than the multiple assign statements for the colours)

Comment: There isn't really an advantage in this case other than readability. If you turn the contents of your for loop into a function, your code would be a little cleaner and you could potentially apply it to other graph lists without needing to repeat code. You could then also use lapply with the function, but I don't think you'd see any speed increase over a for loop.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help, really useful!