# Features do not show on Network plot in R using igraph

Tags: r, networking, plot, igraph

I made a network plot of 44 features, but the names of the features do not show in my network plot. When I run my code, this error shows:

```
Error in symbols(x = coords[, 1], y = coords[, 2], bg = vertex.color,  :
```

invalid symbol parameter

I tried this: [Unable to plot a network on igraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428534/unable-to-plot-a-network-on-igraph), but nothing worked.

Does anyone know what I should change? Here is my code:

```
co <- filter(data) %>%
select(-q, -ID) %>%
  cor()

library(igraph)
g <- graph.adjacency(co,
                            weighted = TRUE,
                            diag = FALSE,
                            mode = "upper")

cut.off_b <- mean(E(g)$weight)

g_2 <- delete_edges(g, E(g)[weight < cut.off_b])

c_g_2 <- cluster_fast_greedy(g_2) 

plot(c_g_2, g_2,
     vertex.size = colSums(co) * 10,
     vertex.frame.color = NA, 
     vertex.label.color = "black", 
     vertex.label.cex = 0.8,
     edge.width = E(g_2)$weight * 15,
     layout = layout_with_fr(g_2),
     main = "Network")
```

dput(co):

```
 structure(c(1, .07977915371083, 0.152143694525588, -0.0218189826329971, 0.0485372722131193, 0.000923129223941082, -0.0222534655849573, 516, 1, -0.205361264538372, -0.149616273645181, 0.241437784766734, -0.140457111733162, 0.52697977722007, 0.588437224079489, -0.00263277091969263, 0.22151603150994, 0.245933601749799, 0.0485372722131193, -0.205361264538372, 1, 0.409240797220096, -0.444516191462303, -0.0553258405959017, 0.224169841776048, 0.286458842414816, -0.00708372057991018, 0.175543278780438, 0.190122437013223, 0.000923129223941082, -0.149616273645181, 0.409240797220096, 1
```

And this is my plot:

[image]

Comment: Please `dput(data)` or `dput(co)` to share your data

Comment: You should share variables co

Comment: Well, what l meant is dput(co)

Comment: You mean this: .Dimnames = list(c("A", "B", "C", "F", "G", 
"H", "K", "L", "N", "P",
"S"), c("A", "B", "C", "F", "G", 
"H", "K", "L", "N", "P",
"S") @ThomasIsCoding

Comment: Nope. You can type `dput (co) ` in console and copy the output to your post. You should share the values in `co`

Comment: Could you put it in your post?

Comment: see update @ThomasIsCoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can try `abs(colSums(co)*10)` for `vertex.size` in `plot`, since it should always be positive value. An example is like below

```
plot(
  c_g_2, g_2,
  vertex.size = abs(colSums(co) * 10),
  vertex.frame.color = NA,
  vertex.label.color = "black",
  vertex.label.cex = 0.8,
  edge.width = E(g_2)$weight,
  layout = layout_with_fr(g_2),
  main = "Network"
)
```

which gives
[image]

**Dummy data**

```
co <- cor(mtcars)
```